BIOS does not see inserted Dell Constellation,2SED HDD on Supermicro X10DRL-I with BPN-SAS3-113A-N2 backplane
Not a hardware guy.
We have a used eight-bay Supermicro (SM) X10DRL-I that came without drives. We have six working Constellation.2SED 1Tb (serial attached scsi) drives salvaged from a disused Power-edge and mounted in the SM 2.5" caddies (these came with the system).  I need to configure the SM so as to use these drives. When the drive caddies are inserted and the system is powered up the BIOS setup shows all SATA and sSATA devices as [not installed].
AHCI is enabled.  The system has a BPN-SAS3-113A-N2 backplane installed.
What do I need to do to get these drives recognized in BIOS?
I do not need a RAID controller on this system as my intention is to install FreeBSD with ZRAID2.
Configuration help is appreciated.

From the board specs:

There's no SAS HBA or controller. SAS drives don't work when connected to a SATA controller. You'll need to get at least a SAS HBA or a RAID controller and connect that to the backplane.
Most SAS HBAs/controllers also talk SATA, but SATA controllers don't talk SAS.

The six drives that we have for this unit are labelled Serial Attached SCSI.  Is that not SAS?

Yes. But the X10DRL-i doesn't talk SAS, only SATA3, according to what I can find.
